# How can I make my bot works in multiple servers?

Tags: discord, discord.js, global

*I know that this question has been asked for discord.py, but couldn't find a discord.js one*

Currently I'm working on a small Discord Bot, and I would like to make it with possible that it can be used in multiple servers. I'm used to the way a bot works in a single server, as I've often made custom bots for a single server usage. But this time, as I'm planning on making the bot public, I would like to make it multi-server enabled, so that multiple people can use it at the same time.

On a side note, I've recently got access to Clyde AI on Discord, and so I used it to help me making this code :
`src/deploy-commands.js`

```js
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const { clientId, token } = require('./../config.json');
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');

const commands = \[\];
const commandsPath = path.join(\__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file =\> file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);

(async () =\> {
    try {
        console.log(\`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.\`);

        const data = await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log(\`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.\`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

The problem that I've with that code, is that it doesn't load any commands into the servers, it just says :
`Started refreshing/reloaded 0 application (/) commands.`

I tried to load the commands using `node deploy-commands.js` (which is the file that I pasted above) in the bot's servers, and I was expecting the console.log to tell me that it correctly loaded all the commands.

It's important to mention that I also removed my guildId from the config.json to enable multi-server usage.

Here are the other code snippets in case you want to see the whole code :

https://codefile.io/f/sKxpBG2uyU - index.js
https://codefile.io/f/YysJDHeJKA - track.js (slash command I'm trying to load)

So to be honest, I'm not sure where to look to fix my error, and where I can update my code to make it work on a multi-server usage.

If anyone of you has an idea, I will greatly take it.

I really hope someone is able to explain me how to make this work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your folder structure look like `src/commands/track.js`?

Comment: @waki285 no it looks like this : ˋsrc/commands/tracking/track.jsˋ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fs.readdirSync does not recursively list directories. Therefore,

```js
const commandsPath = path.join(\__dirname, 'commands');
fs.readdirSync(commandsPath);
```

returns `["tracking"]`. (from comments)
You can retrieve files recursively with code like this:

```js
const readdirSyncRecursively = (dir, files = []) => {
  const paths = fs.readdirSync(dir);
  const dirs = [];
  for (const path of paths) {
    const stats = fs.statSync(`${dir}/${path}`);
    if (stats.isDirectory()) {
      dirs.push(`${dir}/${path}`);
    } else {
      files.push(`${dir}/${path}`);
    }
  }
  for (const d of dirs) {
    files = readdirSyncRecursively(d, files);
  }
  return files;
};
```

so,

```js
const readdirSyncRecursively = (dir, files = []) => {
  const paths = fs.readdirSync(dir);
  const dirs = [];
  for (const path of paths) {
    const stats = fs.statSync(`${dir}/${path}`);
    if (stats.isDirectory()) {
      dirs.push(`${dir}/${path}`);
    } else {
      files.push(`${dir}/${path}`);
    }
  }
  for (const d of dirs) {
    files = readdirSyncRecursively(d, files);
  }
  return files;
};

const commands = [];
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = readdirSyncRecursively(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
```

Comment: I'm not sure, in what file do I put this exactly ?

Comment: I've tried your code, but it still doesn't work. the commandFiles constant is never read actually.

Comment: Never mind what I said right before. I don't know why, but the code wasn't working even though it was the right way to do it. I think I had an old version of my deploy-commands.js script. And updating the `await rest.put(...);` function like they say on the discordjs.guide made it work. Apologize for the inconvenience.